# Integration by substitution, derivative of $g ' (x)$, why?

Tags: integration

First, let's look at the formula for integration by substitution:

$$\int f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = F(g(x))$$

where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

But... I don't get why there's a $g'(x)$?

Example: $(2x-3)^2$. There is NO $g'(x)$ here, only $f(g(x))$ meaning only an inner and outer function... yet I'm supposed to use integration by substitution to solve this one, but how can I do that since it doesn't look like my formula?

Comment: This has nothing to do with integration.

Comment: If $F'(x) = f(x)$, then the *derivative* of $F(g(x))$ is $f(g(x))·g'(x)$, the identity you cited is false.

Comment: Hallo Daniel: what is $F$ (w.r.t. $f$ and $g$, I mean)?

Comment: It's an example from my book, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with integration. Basically, I'm being told to use the formula mentioned in my first post to integrate (2x-3)^2. I know that my f(g(x)) is equal to (2x-3)^2, but I have no g ' (x) multiplied on, so what does that mean?

Comment: Try $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=2x-3$ and note that $g'$ is constant, so it can get in and out of the integral sign.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a $g'(x)$ if you just give it a little hand: the candidate $g(x)$ is obviously $2x-3$, corresponding to $g'(x)=2$.

$(2x-3)^2=\frac{1}{2}.(2x-3)^2.2$

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you left out a symbol in the equation as the left hand side of your equation is actually equal to the derivative of the right hand side.

For your question: The trick here is that with the correct choice of $g(x)$, $g^{\prime}(x)$ will be a constant $c$, and so you can safely make a substitution after "multiplying" your integrand by $\frac{c}{c}$.